# Remove a code from core module without modifying it(using hooks?)

Tags: 7, hooks

Referring to [my question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26738/how-to-remove-the-add-new-comment-link-from-book-pages) about the removal of "Add new comment" link from the book page links area, is there a way to remove the code with the help of *hooks*. I am new to implementing *hooks*. I have found the [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26738/how-to-remove-the-add-new-comment-link-from-book-pages/30175#30175) to the problem, but I need a better way to implement it(maybe by hooks, idk).

**Edit**
I did face a similar problem when I had to comment out the `print $tree` from the core *book module's* `book-navigation.tpl.php`, as it was printing the tree at the bottom of every node, and I didn't want it that way. I used the *tree navigation* block in my sidebar to navigate through the tree structure. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: The question that you linked to has an accepted answer that involves using a hook. Your question is confusing. Are you looking for a generic hook that can be used to remove any code from any module?

Comment: @sheena_d The answer did not solve my question(shouldn't have accepted it).
I want the exact thing which you say. I'm new to *hooks*, and have tried and run numerous *hooks*, but couldn't do it.

Comment: There isn't one generic hook that can alter anything. Modules can create their own hooks that can be used to modify specific pieces of that module's functionality. api.drupal.org is a resource for searching hooks included in the core modules, and most modules include a module_name.api.php file which includes documentation for all of the "hookable" functions within that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The suggested [hook_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6) (in your linked question) does not exist in Drupal 7 so it doesn't work like you already found out. On the API page there's [hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) being mentioned which can be used instead. You can implement this specific hook both in a module and your theme's template.php file. To unset the comment link the following should work (updated based on the comment by Ajit):

```
function myThemeOrModule_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['#node']->type == 'book') {
    unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
  }
}
```

If it's not quite right you can try (in your development environment) finding out what to unset by adding the following line inside the function: `drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($build['links'], TRUE).'</pre>');` (until you have a better tool available).

2) Overriding template files is handled like paul-m already mentioned by creating a copy of the necessary tpl.php file inside your theme folder and doing all the changes there.

3) If you end up needing to override theme functions then you should create a copy of it inside your theme's template.php file where you can modify it.

Don't forget to clear the caches after adding a new function or template.

Comment: thank you so much :-) the hook worked fine with the modification `unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);`
I also checked to see some of the hooks on [API page](http://api.drupal.org) of Drupal.
Real exciting this *hook* stuff is :-)
Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, hooks help a lot in tailoring Drupal to fit different requirements/needs. Glad the answer was useful and thanks for mentioning the correct array element to unset the comment link (makes things easier for possible future visitors) :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the `print $tree` problem, you'd create a new [`book-navigation.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book-navigation.tpl.php/7) template file that doesn't print the $tree. You'd do this in your own theme, which could easily be a subtheme of whichever one you're using.

As for the previous question, [md2 got it right](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29350/4894). Implement this non-theme hook by [creating a module](http://drupal.org/node/361112). It's not that hard. [The Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples) might help you a little, though it doesn't directly address this issue.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The actual problem is I was trying to implement Drupal 6 hook there and so it wasn't executing.
I did found a solution(thanks to Dooshta), in the answer above